# How to show TextView's in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my `.xml`. I want both `TextView` in inside LinearLayout where is `ImageView and TextView`. The problem is that If I put it inside I don't get the text. If is outside like now the text is there. Any idea how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/buttons" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />


</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: put image what you want :)

Comment: Have you any image file? Witch type look are you want?

Comment: All textviews have 300dp width. As well as the linearlayout which is  horizontal.

Comment: your second linear layout has horizontal orientation  ... thts why you cant see other textviews...

Comment: May be I didn't explain properly. The problem are both `TextView` that are in bottom. `"@+id/text"` and `"@+id/menu"`. I want to move them up where are both `Image and TextView`.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand properly. Your LinearLayout is horizontal. All views will be displayed one after the other, and not below. That's why you can't see the other textviews. Because they have 300dp width.

Comment: @PedroOliveira, I've write my comment before to see your and Prag's. I will try now to change on `vertical`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited your code, Check this it will work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Hello" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="HIII" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="HOW" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you use `300dp` for `LinearLayout's` and `TextView's` **layout_width** and you use some padding too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I get all content side by side like this. My goal is image on the left then on right side of image all textviws one under another.

Comment: @JasonPaddle can u post a screenshot what exactly u want

Comment: Picture added in my question. This is what I trying to achieve.

Comment: last two textview placed horizontally?